# Find last and first row for every id

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table:

| id | RANK |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 1 |
| 111 | 2 |
| 111 | 3 |
| 222 | 1 |
| 222 | 2 |

I want to add two colums that will show if this is the first/last  row for each id

| id | first | last |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | YES | NO |
| 111 | NO | NO |
| 111 | NO | YES |
| 222 | YES | NO |
| 222 | NO | YES |

Comment: How so you decide which row's the first/last? (Does your table also have a timestamp or sequence column?)

Comment: Unfortunately, on a bad design you will get bad solutions.
I suggest you will work on those tables design to meet your needs...

Comment: i edited the table by rank

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1):

Let's first point out that sorting without column to sort this is **no good idea**.

Usually, an id is unique and will be incremented, so it will already be sufficient to order by id.

If this is not the case, there should be at least be another column with a meaningful value (for example also an incrementing number or a datetime) which can be used to sort the result.

So you should fix your table design if possible and add such a column or make your already existing id column unique.

If this is not possible and you really have to order just by the row number, you could do following:

```
SELECT id,
CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS first,
CASE WHEN rn = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id) 
THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS last 
FROM 
(
  SELECT
    id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) rn
  FROM yourtable
);
```

If you have a column to sort (let's name it "rank"), this will be much safer:

```
SELECT id,
CASE WHEN rn1 = 1 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS first,
CASE WHEN rn2 = 1 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS last
FROM 
(
  SELECT
   id,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY rank) rn1,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY rank DESC) rn2
  FROM yourtable
);
```

Comment: the condition on `last` can be made simpler - `when rn = count(*) over (partition by id)`

Comment: If there can be duplicates in the ranks then you should use the `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK` analytic functions (instead of `ROW_NUMBER`) as it will return multiple rows if there are ties for first or last.

Comment: If this is intended, yes. I didn't have that impression, but the description is vague

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  test (id, rank) as
  3    (select 111, 1 from dual union all
  4     select 111, 2 from dual union all
  5     select 111, 3 from dual union all
  6     select 222, 1 from dual union all
  7     select 222, 2 from dual
  8    ),
```

Query begins here:

```
  9  temp as
 10    (select id,
 11       rank,
 12       first_value(rank) over (partition by id) rnk_min,
 13       last_value(rank)  over (partition by id ) rnk_max
 14     from test
 15    )
 16  select id,
 17    case when rank = rnk_min then 'Yes' else 'No' end first,
 18    case when rank = rnk_max then 'Yes' else 'No' end last
 19  from temp
 20  order by id, rank;

        ID FIRST   LAST
---------- ------- -------
       111 Yes     No
       111 No      No
       111 No      Yes
       222 Yes     No
       222 No      Yes

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have rows with the same rank per id, you may use `lag/lead` functions to mark first and last rows with a flag using `default` argument of these functions, which is used when the function leaves a window boundary.

```
with sample_tab (id, rank) as (
  select 111, 1 from dual union all
  select 111, 2 from dual union all
  select 111, 3 from dual union all
  select 222, 1 from dual union all
  select 222, 2 from dual
)
select
  id
  , lag('No', 1, 'Yes') over(partition by id order by rank asc) as last
  , lead('No', 1, 'Yes') over(partition by id order by rank asc) as last
from sample_tab
```

| ID | LAST | LAST |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Yes | No |
| 111 | No | No |
| 111 | No | Yes |
| 222 | Yes | No |
| 222 | No | Yes |

If the data may have the same rank for multiple rows per id, you may use the same technique (a case when function goes beyound window boundary) with `coalesce`.

```
with sample_tab (id, rank) as (
  select 111, 1 from dual union all
  select 111, 2 from dual union all
  select 111, 2 from dual union all
  select 222, 1 from dual union all
  select 222, 2 from dual
)
select
  id
  , coalesce(max('No') over(
      partition by id order by rank asc
      /*RANGE for logical offset,
      setting the same flag for a group of first/last rows*/
      range between 1 preceding and 1 preceding
  ), 'Yes') as first
  , coalesce(max('No') over(
      partition by id order by rank asc
      range between 1 following and 1 following
  ), 'Yes') as last
from sample_tab
```

| ID | FIRST | LAST |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Yes | No |
| 111 | No | Yes |
| 111 | No | Yes |
| 222 | Yes | No |
| 222 | No | Yes |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Am2lktqT)